# Issue with JQuery AJAX Perl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl

I have a pretty simplistic login handler for my website that I am having trouble with, user fills in username and password into appropriate input, ajax sends the information to the perl script that checks, and returns a message on whether it was successful or not and that message is placed into a div. Right now ajax just returns "undefined" when i grab the error message with: XMLHttpRequest.responseText. No message result is sent at all. The status, username and password work properly.

JQuery

```
<script>
function login() {
        var login = {
            status: "login",
            username: $('#username').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'bar.cgi',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: login,
                     },
                    }).done(function( msg ) {
                                                $('#result').html( msg );
                                            });
        }
</script>
```

Perl bar.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use JSON;
use Template;

my $q = CGI->new;
my $dbh = DBI->connect( $db, $db_user, $db_pass ) or die("Connection Error: 
+DBI::errstr\n");

my $s = CGI::Session->new("driver:mysql;serializer:storable", $q, {'Handle'=> $dbh }) or 
+die( CGI::Session->errstr );   

if ($q->param('status') eq 'login') {

...check that username/password matches database if so modify session

print $s->header('application/json');
print to_json("login successful");
exit;    
}
```

Comment: what does 'msg' contain? put console.log(msg) instead of $('#result').html( msg.result ); and tell what you see. is it empty?

Comment: msg, should contain "login successful" or "login unsuccessful". I changed to what you suggested and nothing changed.

Comment: I was originally printing a hash to JSON and the key was 'result', that was leftover.

Answer (score 0):

to_json is probably failing since you are not passing it a hash and are just passing a string.

```
$ perl -MJSON -e "print to_json({msg => 'login success'});"
{"msg":"login success"}

$ perl -MJSON -e "print to_json('success');"
hash- or arrayref expected (not a simple scalar, use allow_nonref to allow this) at ...
```

Install firebug or something similar for whatever browser you are using so you can make sure that your json is returning successfully when the ajax call is made.

Check your error logs for whatever server you are using to see if your perl backend is throwing an error.

Comment: On an related note, CGI.pm is relatively aged. There are several perl alternatives for doing modern web development including many frameworks. Here is an [overview](http://modernperl.net/developers/web-application-development.html)